# Stop background audio without reference

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 32 cells and every cell has `onclick="music()"` function. It's working good except one thing. I want it to function so that every time I click another cell the other cell's music stops.

My JavaScript code is:

```
function music(){
    var t = event.target;
    var sound = new Audio();
    sound.src =  "sound/"+t.title+".mp3";
    sound.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I could think of:

```
var playingMusic = {};
var playMusic = function () {}
  var t = event.target;
  playingMusic["sound/"+t.title+".mp3"] = new Audio();
  sound.src =  "sound/"+t.title+".mp3";
  sound.play();
}
var stopMusic = function (key) { // the key being "sound/"+t.title+".mp3"
  playingMusic[key].stop();
}
```

If you need an explanation on something ask and I will update this answer!

Comment: In your solution without reference there will be no `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')` as audio is created and played from javascript.

Comment: I have deleted that part of the answer and thank you for pointing that out to me! @KarthickManoharan

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many ways, one is to use a class and one is to use a global variable for example. Global variable is a simpler one so i explain it here. First a declare a variable on a global scope e.g. let sound;. Then your function could be like this.

```
    function music(){
      if(sound && !sound.paused() {
        sound.pause();
      }

      var t = event.target;
      var newSound = new Audio();
      newSound.src =  "sound/"+t.title+".mp3";
      newSound.play();
      sound = newSound;
    }
```

Comment: This would not work because the old `sound` is out of the function's scope, therefore, creating new music on top of the old each time.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function implementation by creating the sound object once.

```
var sound = undefined;

function music() {
    if (!sound) {
        sound = new Audio();
    } else if(!sound.paused()) {
        sound.pause();
        sound.currentTime = 0; // rewind
    }
    sound.src =  `sound/${event.target.title}.mp3`;
    sound.play();
}
```

Comment: This access `sound` with a reference.